# How to split array of objects into arrays of objects connected with the same value for some property?

Tags: javascript

So I have this array of objects:

```
var users =
 [ 
  { action: 'search', time: 1487098109, name: 'Charlie' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487184715, name: 'Charlie' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487184755, name: 'John' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'John' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'Mark' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487271537, name: 'Mark' },
  { action: 'c', time: 1487098139, name: 'Mike' },
  { action: 'b', time: 1487098169, name: 'Mike' },
  { action: 'a', time: 1487098199, name: 'Mike' },
  { action: 'login', time: 1487098300, name: 'Mike' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1, name: 'Robert' },
  { action: 'search', time: 2, name: 'Robert' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487098169, name: 'Woody' },
  { action: 'search', time: 1487271467, name: 'Woody' } 
 ]
```

And I want to convert it into this structure which is an array of arrays of objects connects by the same name property:

```
[
  [
    { action: 'search', time: 1487098109, name: 'Charlie' },
    { action: 'search', time: 1487184715, name: 'Charlie' }
  ],
  [
    { action: 'search', time: 1487184755, name: 'John' },
    { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'John' }
  ],
  [
    { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'Mark' },
    { action: 'search', time: 1487271537, name: 'Mark' }
  ],
  [
    { action: 'c', time: 1487098139, name: 'Mike' },
    { action: 'b', time: 1487098169, name: 'Mike' },
    { action: 'a', time: 1487098199, name: 'Mike' },
    { action: 'login', time: 1487098300, name: 'Mike' }
  ],
  [
    { action: 'search', time: 1, name: 'Robert' },
    { action: 'search', time: 2, name: 'Robert' }
  ],
  [
    { action: 'search', time: 1487098169, name: 'Woody' },
    { action: 'search', time: 1487271467, name: 'Woody' }
  ]
]
```

So how can I accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cool. So, [what have you tried](/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: See [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort and then execute the function `reduce` to group the objects by name.

```js
var users = [   { action: 'search', time: 1487098109, name: 'Charlie' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487184715, name: 'Charlie' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487184755, name: 'John' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'John' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487271527, name: 'Mark' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487271537, name: 'Mark' },  { action: 'c', time: 1487098139, name: 'Mike' },  { action: 'b', time: 1487098169, name: 'Mike' },  { action: 'a', time: 1487098199, name: 'Mike' },  { action: 'login', time: 1487098300, name: 'Mike' },  { action: 'search', time: 1, name: 'Robert' },  { action: 'search', time: 2, name: 'Robert' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487098169, name: 'Woody' },  { action: 'search', time: 1487271467, name: 'Woody' }  ];

var result = Object.values(users.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).reduce((a, c) => {
  (a[c.name] || (a[c.name] = [])).push(c);
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Ele for your help